# why does ja_orisite joomla template loads default css after any module installation

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-template

I am using Joomlart.com's JA_ORISITE template for my site, Everything works perfect except the css, It might be a feature of the template to maintains its original design, but This feature is a big hurdle for me. I have changed the css of the template as per my requirements, but every time I load or install a new module or plugin in to my installation, Default css is being loaded automatically, so Every time I need to fix the css as per my requirements and this frustrates me....

Glad to see any possible solution....  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T3 framework uses LESS to compile the CSS being used by the template. LESS is recompile for a multitude of reasons and it sounds like installing a new extension is one of them. When LESS is recompiled, you will lose any edits you have made to the CSS.

In order to made CSS edits that are not overwritten by LESS you have to put any custom CSS in custom.css. The template is configured not to touch that file so your changes are not lost.

Documentation is here - http://t3-framework.org/documentation/customization.html#custom-css

Comment: where to save the  custom.css file, and how to load it in joomla site.

Comment: In the template css folder. It has to be named custom.css and it is loaded by the template automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What file did you edit to make your customizations? I'm guessing you edited one of the included CSS files in the template. Your best bet is to make a new custom.css file and add that to the css being loading in index.php.

Comment: I edit the required css under the folder "t3_assets", whenever the module or plugin is installed, automatically the a new css file is being created, even though my edited file is as it is....
once the new css file is created automatically it is being used by the template.

Comment: Ok, I looked at the T3 documentation and have an answer for you. I'll add a new answer.